# logrotate not rotating logs based on size

Tags: linux, logging, logrotate

I am using logrotate to rotate the test.log log files available in the directory /var/test/log. Below is the snippet of logrotate configuration file

> ## DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE.
>
> /var/test/log/test.log { daily nocompress copytruncate missingok
> rotate 10 size 2M }

As seen in the configuration, the size of the file should be 2Mb and if the file grows beyond this it should get rotated, but it is not happening when i try to execute the below command

> /usr/sbin/logrotate -d /var/test/testlogrotate
> reading config file /var/test/testlogrotate
> reading config info for /var/test/log/test.log
>
> Handling 1 logs
>
> rotating pattern: /var/test/log/test.log  2097152 bytes (10 rotations)
> empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed considering log
> /var/test/log/test.log   log needs rotating rotating log
> /var/test/log/test.log, log->rotateCount is 10 renaming
> /var/test/log/test.log.10 to /var/test/log/test.log.11 (rotatecount
> 10, logstart 1, i 10), renaming /var/test/log/test.log.9 to
> /var/test/log/test.log.10 (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 9), renaming
> /var/test/log/test.log.8 to /var/test/log/test.log.9 (rotatecount 10,
> logstart 1, i 8), renaming /var/test/log/test.log.7 to
> /var/test/log/test.log.8 (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 7), renaming
> /var/test/log/test.log.6 to /var/test/log/test.log.7 (rotatecount 10,
> logstart 1, i 6), renaming /var/test/log/test.log.5 to
> /var/test/log/test.log.6 (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 5), renaming
> /var/test/log/test.log.4 to /var/test/log/test.log.5 (rotatecount 10,
> logstart 1, i 4), renaming /var/test/log/test.log.3 to
> /var/test/log/test.log.4 (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 3), renaming
> /var/test/log/test.log.2 to /var/test/log/test.log.3 (rotatecount 10,
> logstart 1, i 2), renaming /var/test/log/test.log.1 to
> /var/test/log/test.log.2 (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 1), renaming
> /var/test/log/test.log.0 to /var/test/log/test.log.1 (rotatecount 10,
> logstart 1, i 0), copying /var/test/log/test.log to
> /var/test/log/test.log.1 truncating /var/test/log/test.log removing
> old log /var/test/log/test.log.11

but i don't see any of the files like test.log.1 in /var/test/log directory. Also i could see that the size of the test.log file to be 2.3Mb.

Help me in trouble shooting this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `-d` which implies debug mode of logrotate. In debug mode logrotate only simulates its actions. No real actions are taken. From [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate):

```
-d, --debug

Turns on debug mode and implies -v. In debug mode, no changes will be made to the logs or to the logrotate state file.
```